# getting Types of referenced project via Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm getting the Type of a class via given [string] name of that class.

```
// a local (in this startup project) public class works fine
Type test = System.Reflection.TypeInfo.GetType("Learning.Models.Production");
Console.WriteLine(test.Name.ToString()); 
// prints "Production"
```

Now, in my solution I have 3 different (referenced) projects. In each of these I can get the Types of it's own Project classes. But I cannot get them cross-project wise:

```
// a public class from a referenced project in this solution - returns null
Type test2 = System.Reflection.TypeInfo.GetType("JeffData.Store");
Console.WriteLine(test2.Name.ToString()); 
// System.NullReferenceException (because test2 is null)
```

further testing:

```
// this is working
Type t1 = System.Reflection.TypeInfo.GetType("System.String");
Console.WriteLine(t1.Name.ToString()); // prints "String"

// but not this (also a public class)
Type t2 = System.Reflection.TypeInfo.GetType("System.Web.HtmlString");
Console.WriteLine(t2.Name.ToString());

// neither that: a public class of another referenced assembly - returns null
Type t3 = System.Reflection.TypeInfo.GetType("Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert");
Console.WriteLine(t3.Name.ToString());
```

From other somehow related questions (though very old) I tested to set
    `[assembly: ComVisible(true)]`
without success (I also learned that I should rather not do that unless really needed).

I also tried setting `Embed Interop Type` in the reference properties to true, because it sounded like it could help:

[image]

So the question is what else I can do to be able to get the Type of such a referenced project.

*EDIT:*

Thanks to @Hans Passant's comments I made it work in two variations:

```
// go via the Assembly
Type test = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(JeffData.Store)).GetType("JeffData.Store");

// provide FullyQualifiedTypeName
Type test = System.Reflection.TypeInfo.GetType("JeffData.RecordStore,JeffData");
```

Comment: have you tried passing the assembly information?

Comment: no, how could I do that?

Comment: You must use the [fully qualified type name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/specifying-fully-qualified-type-names), so the CLR can determine what assembly needs to be loaded to provide the type.  Or use Assembly.GetType().  If it is a referenced assembly then there is no point in making it difficult, just use the typeof operator.

Comment: `"JeffData.Store"` is the full name including namespace, isn't it? I can only use the typeof operator with hardcoded Types. Not if I get them as string...

Comment: It is not, the CLR has no idea what assembly provides this type.

Comment: thanks, just read it in you link. So if the Assembly Name is "JeffData" and the namespace is "JeffData" it'll be "JeffData.JeffData.Classname"??

Comment: I think it would be easier with .Net Compiler Services (Roslyn) because you can load everything within a solution. Is that an option for you?

Comment: @Crowcoder I'll have a look at that!

Comment: @HansPassant this worked out: `Type test = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(JeffData.Store)).GetType("JeffData.Store");`

Comment: I'd be happy to accept an answer!

Comment: also this is working: `Type test = System.Reflection.TypeInfo.GetType("JeffData.RecordStore,JeffData");`